Expo router: new page using router.push within same folder doesn't push but replaces Instead
I encountered an issue while working on our project. When I try to navigate to a new page within the same folder using router.push in React Native, I noticed that instead of adding a new page to the stack, it gets replaced.
Example: https://github.com/andreavrr/router-push-slot
